# JQuery: Hiding dynamically added images via generated ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a program in JavaScript that functions similar to a "Whack-a-Mole" game.  I have everything figured out except for one thing.  I would like to have each "mole" disappear after a brief time if it is not clicked on.  The function that generates the moles is shown below.  I am not entirely sure how to go about hiding the moles, but I would like to do so by selecting them by a uniquely generated ID, as shown in the code.  There is a global variable "count" that is used to generate each ID.

```
function addMole(){
var yPos = numOne();
var xPos = numTwo();

if (timeLeft > 0){
$("#gamespace").append('<img id="i'+count+'" src="img/mole.gif" style="top:'+yPos+'px;left:'+xPos+'px;" />');
count++;
setTimeout("addMole()", Math.floor(Math.random()*2000));
};
};
```

I have tried using this function, but it doesn't seem to do anything and I'm not sure how or where to call it or if I'm even using the right selector.

```
function noMole(){
$("#i"+count).delay(2000).hide();

};
```

Comment: `delay()` is not a replacement for `setTimeout`.  delay is intended to be used with jQuery operations that involve a use of it's internal animation queues.  Use setTimeout instead.

Comment: `setTimeout("addMole()", Math.floor(Math.random()*2000));` should be `setTimeout(addMole, Math.floor(Math.random()*2000));`

Comment: Also, at least from the code you have here, it looks like `count` is a pretty global variable, so you're going to have issue trying to use that as is in your timed lookup for removal

Comment: That's not a selector.  The first argument to setTimeout is a function reference.  `addMole` is the name of a function, thus a reference.  https://jsfiddle.net/e5u0h2mt/

Comment: It's not a suggestion, it's just the valid way to call function using `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with something like the following:

```js
function addMole() {
  var yPos = numOne();
  var xPos = numTwo();

  if (timeLeft > 0) {
    //make a new mole and have a reference to it
    var newMole = $('<img src="img/mole.gif" style="top:' + yPos + 'px;left:' + xPos + 'px;" />');
    //put the mole in the game
    $("#gamespace").append(newMole);
    //add another mole in a random amount of time
    setTimeout(addMole, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000));
    //remove the created mole after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){ newMole.remove(); }, 5000);
  };
};
```

You don't need a lookup.  You just need the reference.

Comment: This works beautifully!  And it's far cleaner than any of the things I was coming up with.